# What is the worst can happen in java race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, atomic

I know this is clearly a race condition. But what are the possible things that can happen?

```
class Blah {
    List<String> stuff;
    public List<String> getStuff() {
        return stuff
    }
    public void setStuff(List<String> newValue) {
        this.stuff = newValue
    }
}

b = new Blah();
// Thread one
b.setStuff(getListFromSomeNetworkResource());
for (String c : b.getStuff()) {
  // Work with c
}


// Thread two
b.setStuff(getListFromSomeNetworkResource());
for (String c : b.getStuff()) {
  // Work with c
}
```

1. Can this throw RuntimeException?
2. Can this segfault jvm?
3. Can this segfault one of the thread?
4. Does it depend on processor. What if it is an Intel Xeon processor?
5. Can this throw a NullPointer exception?
6. Thread 2 can read the contents set by Thread 1 and vice versa if the function actually returned different values

I understand this is a race condition and will not write such a code. But How do I convince others not to?

**Update:**

Assumptions:

1. `getListFromSomeNetworkResource()` always returns a new `ArrayList`. Size may be 0 or more.
2. `getListFromSomeNetworkResource()` is thread safe.

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

> Can this throw RuntimeException?

No, *if* `getListFromSomeNetworkResource()` is thread-safe and doesn't return `null`.

> Can this segfault jvm?
>
> Can this segfault one of the thread?
>
> Does it depend on processor. What if it is an Intel Xeon processor?

No.

> Can this throw a NullPointer exception?

only if `getListFromSomeNetworkResource()` can return `null`.

> Thread 2 can read the contents set by Thread 1 and vice versa if the function actually returned different values

yes, this is likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The danger would be an ordering such as:

1. Thread one: `b.setStuff(getListFromSomeNetworkResource());`
2. Thread two: `b.setStuff(getListFromSomeNetworkResource());`
3. Thread one: `b.stuff.iterator()` (via `b.getStuff()`, at the start of the *for* loop)

In this case, thread one *may* be iterating over the list that thread two set. That publication, from thread two to thread one, was done without any synchronization -- that's a data race. Assuming that list is not itself thread-safe, lots of things can happen. The main issue would be that some of the list's state is visible to thread one, but not all of it, due to that data race.

- It may throw some RuntimeException. For instance, maybe one field thinks that the list has `n` elements due to a resize. But the new array that came from that resize didn't make it over, so you end up with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
- It may throw a NullPointerException for any number of reasons; maybe it's a linked list, and one of the reference writes didn't make it to thread one

It should not cause any segfaults: those can only come about from bugs in the JVM, but never bugs in your code.

It may depend on the processor, in that processors may have different handling of things like flushing memory from one CPU cache to another -- that's one of the reasons that unsafe publication can cause you to see only some of the data that one thread wrote, from another thread. There are ways to force those caches to get flushed; the way to specify them in Java is through the various data synchronization mechanisms (acquiring locks, using volatile fields, etc).

Comment: >> thread one may be iterating over the list that thread two set
Is this really possible?  Isn't the iterator local to the object and both threads have different objects?

Comment: Both threads share the same `b` instance, though, and so both can share the same `b.stuff` reference. The iterator is indeed thread-local, but its backing list is not. In my example above, with the steps ordered as I have them, think about which object `b.stuff` references in the third step.

Comment: Ooh, a drive-by downvote more than a month and a half after. That's new. :-) Any chance for a comment explaining?